# 415 status code on using consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to consume a json into a java object using spring mvc rest. But getting 415 status code.

spring-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz.controllers" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

RestController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hellouser", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> helloHomer(@RequestBody Home home) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(home.getFirst() + home.getSecond(),
            HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Home bean:

```
public class Home {
    private String first = "defaultFirst";
    private String second = "defaultSecond";
    public String getFirst() {
        return first;
    }
    public void setFirst(String first) {
        this.first = first;
    }
    public String getSecond() {
        return second;
    }
    public void setSecond(String second) {
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

POM.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Tested using different rest clients with but getting 415 status code.

```
Accept=application/json
{"first" : "first"
  "second" : "second"}
```

Trying to understand the issue and fix.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass Content-Type=application/json as a request header while invoking the service from rest client

Comment: Thanks. Working as expected.